# git-status и переименования

Tags: git

Вот так я могу посмотреть `git-diff`, указав «похожесть»
файлов для назначения им статуса «переименованных» в 20 %:

```sh
$ git diff --find-renames=20%
```

Есть ли что-то подобное для `git-status`?  Чтобы вместо:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

    deleted:    a.txt
    new file:   b.txt
```

Получить:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

    renamed:    a.txt -> b.txt
```

Comment: а опция `--find-renames` не помогает?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ``unknown option `find-renames=20%'``

Comment: пропустили два минуса в начале? слишком старая версия программы?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  Ваша вторая версия оказалась верной.  Записал в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря участнику `aleksandr barakin` понял, в чём дело.
У меня версия **2.17.1**, стандартная для *Ubuntu* 18.04, а Гит
научился использовать `--find-renames`
в `git-status` только в **2.18.0**:

```sh
$ sed -n '117, 120 p' './Documentation/RelNotes/2.18.0.txt'
```

```
* "git status" learned to honor a new status.renames configuration to
   skip rename detection, which could be useful for those who want to
   do so without disabling the default rename detection done by the
   "git diff" command.
```

После сборки более свежей версии всё работает.